# Vue.js: Why isn't component rendered ?

Tags: vue.js

I wrote a very simple vue.js application to learn how to work with vue files.

Here is the code:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <article></article>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data: function() {
        return {

        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**main.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Article from './Article.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('article', Article);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

**Article.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>bla bla</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {

            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

I expect to see 'bla bla' in the browser. However, when I open the browser, I see white page. The console says:

> [Vue warn]: Do not use built-in or reserved HTML elements as component
>   id: article

and when I open Vue dev tools this is what I see: 
[image]

No Article component has been added. Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the html tag `article` as a component name. Rename it and it should render.

For example:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('article2', {
  template: '<div>Hi there</div>'
});

Vue.component('app', {
  template: '<article2></article2>'
})

new Vue({
  render: h => h('app'),
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call components in main.js not the best structure + you don't call him in Vue instance, example:

**Article.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>bla bla</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'article'
    }
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <article></article>
</template>

<script>
import article from './Article';

export default {
    components: {
      article,
   },
}
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

I hope this work with you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're just rendering App:

```
render: h => h(App),
```

You should rather import Article in App and use like:

```
<template>
    <article></article>
</template>

<script>
import Article from './Article.vue'
export default {
    components: { article: Article },
    data: function() {
        return {

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And remove the followings from App:

```
import Article from './Article.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('article', Article);
```

---

But article is html5 element, so I suggest you to use another name like:

```
components: {
  myArticle: Article
}

<my-article></my-article>
```